# Definition: Gauss Sum - Where is the error?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, definition, gauss-sums

In my algebraic number theory lecture we defined Gauss sums as follows. However, I am quite unsure whether this definition is correct. My intuition says "there is a mistake somewhere". I tried double-checking with Pierre Samuels book (§5.5, page 78), but Samuel uses slightly different notation.

If there is indeed a mistake in my defintion, would somebody be so kind and give me a clean (standard) defintion of Gauss sums.

> [image: Gauss Sums]

Comment: Typically, they use $\zeta = \exp(2\pi i /p)$, though "Primitive $p$-th root of unity" can be any $\exp(2\pi i k/p)$ where $0<k<p$.

Comment: But in the definition, $K$ could be $\mathbb F_p$, and $\exp(2\pi ik/p)$ is not necessarily in $\mathbb F_p$, or is it? :/

Comment: Oh, I missed that. I only considered complex field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think that $\zeta$ should be a primitive $q$-th (not $p$-th) root of unity.  In characteristic $p$, the only $p$-th root of unity is unity.  That's because $x^p-1=(x-1)^p$ in characteristic $p$; the cross-terms that you'd ordinarily expect have coefficients that are divisible by $p$ and thus vanish in characteristic $p$.